# Angular Autocomplete doesn't seem to work right

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I'm trying to do the following form with an input with autocomplete but I'd like that the user only could select the items on the autocomplete list but with the possibility to search the item to select:

```
<mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="formTclimit.value.hideRequired" [floatLabel]="formTclimit.value.floatLabel" class="col-4">
   <input class="search" type="text" matInput formControlName="codename" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{'placeholder.search'|translate}}" (click)="searchStation()" [matAutocomplete]="tclstation" (change)="validateSelectedStation($event.target.value)">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete class="col-4" #tclstation="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredListStations | async" [value]="item.codename" (click)="onChangeStation(item.stationcode, item.stationname, item.codename)">{{item.codename}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

The problem is that when autocomplete is filtering not always click event (on mat-option) is triggered and change event (on input) is always triggered.

Any idea about that? Is there a way to prioritize click over change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using reactive forms, I would suggest you to listen to form control [valueChanges](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#managing-control-values) event, which will be triggered whenever an option is selected.

```
ngOnInit() {  
   this.myForm.get('codename').valueChanges.subscribe( val => console.log(val));
}
```